# Automated script for controller auto-connect fails

Tags: shell, raspberry-pi, bluetooth

I am trying to auto-connect my PS5 controller to Raspberry. I am using this script in `/home/pi/bt.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

coproc bluetoothctl

echo -e 'scan on\n' >&${COPROC[1]}
sleep 3
echo -e 'connect 3C:C9:9D:54:E2:1C\n' >&${COPROC[1]}
sleep 1

echo -e 'scan off\n' >&${COPROC[1]}
echo -e 'exit\n' >&${COPROC[1]}

output=$(cat <&${COPROC[0]})
echo $output
```

I edited `sudo nano /etc/rc.local` into this:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

# Print the IP address
_IP=$(hostname -I) || true
if [ "$_IP" ]; then
  printf "My IP address is %s\n" "$_IP"
fi

/home/pi/bt.sh &

exit 0
```

Controller connects on boot for a few seconds and then turns off. Why? How do I fix this?

dmesg output:

```
[   19.266779] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   19.266900] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[   19.266911] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   19.266939] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   19.266957] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   19.266986] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   19.285056] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[   19.285077] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[   19.285185] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[   19.285573] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Broadcom registered
[   19.719726] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   19.719738] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   19.719756] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   19.751825] NET: Registered protocol family 38
[   19.803472] cryptd: max_cpu_qlen set to 1000
[   20.410378] Bluetooth: HIDP (Human Interface Emulation) ver 1.2
[   20.410403] Bluetooth: HIDP socket layer initialized
[   20.498154] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   20.498179] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   20.498210] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   20.955136] vc4-drm soc:gpu: [drm] Cannot find any crtc or sizes
[   21.977207] hid-generic 0005:054C:0CE6.0001: unknown main item tag 0x0
[   21.977731] input: Wireless Controller as /devices/platform/soc/3f201000.serial/tty/ttyAMA0/hci0/hci0:11/0005:054C:0CE6.0001/input/input4
[   21.986045] hid-generic 0005:054C:0CE6.0001: input,hidraw0: BLUETOOTH HID v1.00 Gamepad [Wireless Controller] on b8:27:eb:a5:84:e4
```

Comment: post the output of dmesg

Comment: added the dmesg